# How to prevent float and negative input using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, input, numbers

I'm using readlineSync.questionInt and I need to prompt a message if the user types float or negative number. I used a limit, but it isn't enough.

```
var readlineSync = require('readline-sync');
var number_of_people = readlineSync.questionInt('How many people are you going with?', { limit: 0 - 9 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use just `question` and move your custom login into `limit` callback. For instance, one idea could be checking if the input is an integer and it is in the range between `0-9`:

```
var readlineSync = require('readline-sync');
var number_of_people = readlineSync.question('How many people are you going with?', {
  limit: function(i) {
    const input = Number(i);
    return  Number.isInteger(input) && input > 0 && input < 10;
}});
```

You could also make use of regexp; just have your callback return `true` when the input is valid based on your logic